# Getting started with 2SXC Bootstrap 4 Instant Theme

Tags: 2sxc

I've installed Bootstrap 4 Instant Theme on my dev machine, which has DNN installed. I can get the theme up OK.
I've installed Node.js and that looks OK.

I've run `npm ci` in the app/theme folder, and that seems to have run OK. There is a webpack.config.js file in the folder.

I don't get the "run webpack" instruction!

When I make changes to the _variables.scss file and save and then refresh my page, I don't get the theme updates.

The Client Resource Management was already disabled.

I've cleared the cache and restarted the application.

What am I missing, or what is missing from the documentation that it assumes I know?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: did you compile the scss? As Bootstrap 4 uses SASS, the scss need to be compiled in order to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

cmd is enough to run the command. I use a .bat with this to quick compile.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm run webpack` from commandline.

I have extended the [instructions](https://azing.org/2sxc/r/BgwBvo1e) and explained the step better. I hope you were able to move on by now.

João Gomes, thx for your quick answer =)